# disabling scrolling on the body given changing attributes

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup, scroll

So I have made a pop-up to display some information on my site, but I made it with fixed dimensions as to make it fit a certain way. This means that there is a scrollbar and you need to scroll on the pop-up, which is fine, my issue is that when you hit the bottom of the pop-up, it starts to scroll on the actual page.

What I want is to disable that. Clearly it must be with some Jquery, but I don't know how I would go about disabling scrolling on the whole page in certain circumstances.

Here is my Jquery for the pop-up:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#example').animate({
            display:'visible',
            opacity:'toggle'
        });
    },
    function(){
        $('#example').animate({
            display:'none',
            opacity:'toggle'
        });
    });
});
```

the `toggle` function wasn't working, so I just doubled with `click` and it works fine. Here is a jsfiddle with everything: http://jsfiddle.net/gYGgr/1/

So what do I need to add to my jquery that will disable scrolling on the body and not the pop-up if the pop-up is open? Thank you!

Comment: why you made it with fixed dimensions?

Comment: because that's how I wanted to style it for the site. The purpose is a sort of updates list, but it could go on and pop ups don't look good long unless they are set in fixed containers

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add `overflow: hidden` to the `<body>` tag in CSS - but I would be cautious about it, since any excess would be hidden. You can always only apply that when the dialog is present though.

Comment: that seems like it could end very poorly if the viewer is in the middle of the page when they get the pop-up?

Answer (score -1):

I think easiest option would be to wrap the boxes in another div with position: fixed. Please have a look at an jsfiddle i worked for you:

`Js Fiddle`

Hope that helps.

Comment: -1, if you read the question and the title, you would see that I only want the no scroll on body if the pop up is open. This does not answer the question

Comment: Don't make me feel like I have wasted my time doing this. My example demonstrate clearly what you've asked for. Sometime its pretty much a guess when your question doesn't make it clear and also your little effort to understand others answer. If you dont like div wrapping boxes you can fixed the body position as I have done in another http://jsfiddle.net/sanman/j8uBH/ example.

Comment: Again, it is only supposed to not scroll if the pop up is open. and if the pop up is not open, then it is supposed to be able to scroll...I mention that clearly in my question and in the jsfiddle. Not trying to attack you, if you can edit it with some jquery so it wont scroll given the right conditions I will gladly mark your solution as correct, but right now this does not answer my question